# Display embed images in HTML emails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-email, mailkit

I store emails as .eml files by Mailkit IMAP and when user want to open mails i open that eml file and display the content and attachments of email

```
var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("E\\sampleEmail.eml"));
var msg = new MsgReader.Mime.Message(file);
ViewBag.Body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.HtmlBody == null ? msg.TextBody.Body : msg.HtmlBody.Body);
```

HtmlBody of emails contains everything but how can i display embed images on html?

img tag shows like this and has cid:

```
<img src="cid:image001.png@01d4330b.ed93f2e0" id="_x0000_i1025">
```

image001 is an attachment of eml file and its embed on html content of email body, what is the best way to display images directly where they are?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are saving the messages downloaded from IMAP using MailKit, then you can reload the message like this:

```
var message = MimeMessage.Load (fileName);
```

Then, to get the message body text, you can do this:

```
string body = message.HtmlBody ?? message.TextBody;
```

Now, to answer your question about how to render images using MimeKit/MailKit, you can take a look at the sample message viewer here: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/tree/master/samples/MessageReader/MessageReader

The important bit is the [HtmlPreviewVisitor](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/samples/MessageReader/MessageReader/HtmlPreviewVisitor.cs):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Text;
using MimeKit.Tnef;

namespace MessageReader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Visits a MimeMessage and generates HTML suitable to be rendered by a browser control.
    /// </summary>
    class HtmlPreviewVisitor : MimeVisitor
    {
        readonly List<MultipartRelated> stack = new List<MultipartRelated> ();
        readonly List<MimeEntity> attachments = new List<MimeEntity> ();
        string body;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new HtmlPreviewVisitor.
        /// </summary>
        public HtmlPreviewVisitor ()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The list of attachments that were in the MimeMessage.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<MimeEntity> Attachments {
            get { return attachments; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The HTML string that can be set on the BrowserControl.
        /// </summary>
        public string HtmlBody {
            get { return body ?? string.Empty; }
        }

        protected override void VisitMultipartAlternative (MultipartAlternative alternative)
        {
            // walk the multipart/alternative children backwards from greatest level of faithfulness to the least faithful
            for (int i = alternative.Count - 1; i >= 0 && body == null; i--)
                alternative[i].Accept (this);
        }

        protected override void VisitMultipartRelated (MultipartRelated related)
        {
            var root = related.Root;

            // push this multipart/related onto our stack
            stack.Add (related);

            // visit the root document
            root.Accept (this);

            // pop this multipart/related off our stack
            stack.RemoveAt (stack.Count - 1);
        }

        // look up the image based on the img src url within our multipart/related stack
        bool TryGetImage (string url, out MimePart image)
        {
            UriKind kind;
            int index;
            Uri uri;

            if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString (url, UriKind.Absolute))
                kind = UriKind.Absolute;
            else if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString (url, UriKind.Relative))
                kind = UriKind.Relative;
            else
                kind = UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute;

            try {
                uri = new Uri (url, kind);
            } catch {
                image = null;
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = stack.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if ((index = stack[i].IndexOf (uri)) == -1)
                    continue;

                image = stack[i][index] as MimePart;
                return image != null;
            }

            image = null;

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the attachent content as a data URI.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The data URI.</returns>
        /// <param name="attachment">The attachment.</param>
        string GetDataUri (MimePart attachment)
        {
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream ()) {
                attachment.Content.DecodeTo (memory);
                var buffer = memory.GetBuffer ();
                var length = (int) memory.Length;
                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String (buffer, 0, length);

                return string.Format ("data:{0};base64,{1}", attachment.ContentType.MimeType, base64);
            }
        }

        // Replaces <img src=...> urls that refer to images embedded within the message with
        // "file://" urls that the browser control will actually be able to load.
        void HtmlTagCallback (HtmlTagContext ctx, HtmlWriter htmlWriter)
        {
            if (ctx.TagId == HtmlTagId.Image && !ctx.IsEndTag && stack.Count > 0) {
                ctx.WriteTag (htmlWriter, false);

                // replace the src attribute with a file:// URL
                foreach (var attribute in ctx.Attributes) {
                    if (attribute.Id == HtmlAttributeId.Src) {
                        MimePart image;
                        string url;

                        if (!TryGetImage (attribute.Value, out image)) {
                            htmlWriter.WriteAttribute (attribute);
                            continue;
                        }

                        url = GetDataUri (image);

                        htmlWriter.WriteAttributeName (attribute.Name);
                        htmlWriter.WriteAttributeValue (url);
                    } else {
                        htmlWriter.WriteAttribute (attribute);
                    }
                }
            } else if (ctx.TagId == HtmlTagId.Body && !ctx.IsEndTag) {
                ctx.WriteTag (htmlWriter, false);

                // add and/or replace oncontextmenu="return false;"
                foreach (var attribute in ctx.Attributes) {
                    if (attribute.Name.ToLowerInvariant () == "oncontextmenu")
                        continue;

                    htmlWriter.WriteAttribute (attribute);
                }

                htmlWriter.WriteAttribute ("oncontextmenu", "return false;");
            } else {
                // pass the tag through to the output
                ctx.WriteTag (htmlWriter, true);
            }
        }

        protected override void VisitTextPart (TextPart entity)
        {
            TextConverter converter;

            if (body != null) {
                // since we've already found the body, treat this as an attachment
                attachments.Add (entity);
                return;
            }

            if (entity.IsHtml) {
                converter = new HtmlToHtml {
                    HtmlTagCallback = HtmlTagCallback
                };
            } else if (entity.IsFlowed) {
                var flowed = new FlowedToHtml ();
                string delsp;

                if (entity.ContentType.Parameters.TryGetValue ("delsp", out delsp))
                    flowed.DeleteSpace = delsp.ToLowerInvariant () == "yes";

                converter = flowed;
            } else {
                converter = new TextToHtml ();
            }

            body = converter.Convert (entity.Text);
        }

        protected override void VisitTnefPart (TnefPart entity)
        {
            // extract any attachments in the MS-TNEF part
            attachments.AddRange (entity.ExtractAttachments ());
        }

        protected override void VisitMessagePart (MessagePart entity)
        {
            // treat message/rfc822 parts as attachments
            attachments.Add (entity);
        }

        protected override void VisitMimePart (MimePart entity)
        {
            // realistically, if we've gotten this far, then we can treat this as an attachment
            // even if the IsAttachment property is false.
            attachments.Add (entity);
        }
    }
}
```

And the way to use the above code along with a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser is this:

```
void Render ()
{
    var visitor = new HtmlPreviewVisitor ();
    message.Accept (visitor);

    webBrowser.DocumentText = visitor.HtmlBody;
}
```

What the HtmlPreviewVisitor does is to embed the image attachments into the HTML using the "data:" URL scheme in the `<img>` tags.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I use a library named MSGReader.

Git:
https://github.com/Sicos1977/MSGReader

In general rules:
This id: "cid:image001.png@01d4330b.ed93f2e0" is a link to the end of the file, images are stored like base64. I did some changes in MSGReader, I will make a pull request soon as possible, did work very well for me.

Comment: Did you make that request, this is something we need too.  Thanks.

Comment: Would like this too.

Answer (score 0):

```
MailMessage mailWithImg = getMailWithImg();
MySMTPClient.Send(mailWithImg); //* Set up your SMTPClient before!

private MailMessage getMailWithImg() {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.AlternateViews.Add(getEmbeddedImage("c:/image.png"));
    mail.From = new MailAddress("yourAddress@yourDomain");
    mail.To.Add("recipient@hisDomain");
    mail.Subject = "yourSubject";
    return mail;
}
private AlternateView getEmbeddedImage(String filePath) {
    LinkedResource res = new LinkedResource(filePath);
    res.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string htmlBody = @"<img src='cid:" + res.ContentId + @"'/>";
    AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res);
    return alternateView;
}
```

Comment: I want to display that not generate